# Syntax Error #1064 when using MariaDB JSON_REPLACE function

Tags: syntax, mariadb, sql-function

I'm using MariaDB version 10.3.39.
I have create a table named "sys_config" with multiple columns.
A column name is "json_system". It's data type is assigned to "longtext".
Using this reference:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_replace/

I have inserted `{ "A": 1, "B": [2, 3]}` in this column.

When I query

`SELECT json_system FROM sys_config`

everything goes ok.

[image: OK]

But when I try to query:

`SELECT JSON_REPLACE(SELECT json_system FROM sys_config, '$.B[1]', 4)`

A Syntax Error will be occurred:
[image: Syntax Error]

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT json_system FROM sys_config, '$.B[1]', 4) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Why this happen? According to MariaDB reference when I query:
`SELECT JSON_REPLACE('{ "A": 1, "B": [2, 3]}', '$.B[1]', 4);`
the query will be successful:

[image: OK]
What's wrong with the second query? When I pass the "SELECT" result into the "JSON_REPLACE" function a syntax error will be appeared.

I have tried below query:
`SELECT JSON_REPLACE('{ "A": 1, "B": [2, 3]}', '$.B[1]', 4);`

This works.

But the query:

`SELECT JSON_REPLACE(SELECT json_system FROM sys_config, '$.B[1]', 4)`

doesn't work.

Comment: the query make no sense at all, the inner select will return a lot of rows, but json_repace needs there a json not a bunch of rows

Comment: @nbk the table only has one row. It does not make a difference whether the database table has one row or several rows. The syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using a `SELECT` query as an expression, it must be enclosed in an [extra] pair of parens:

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE((SELECT json_system FROM ...))
                    ^                           ^
```

Comment: Thanks. This query `SELECT JSON_REPLACE((SELECT json_system FROM sys_config), '$.B[1]', 4)` worked for me. What I noticed is that if I use `SELECT JSON_REPLACE(SELECT json_system FROM sys_config, '$.B[1]', 4)` then the MariaDB will considers `sys_config,` as an extension of the expression, not the second argument of `JSON_REPLACE`.